# eXist-db Maven Dependencies

Tags: maven, exist-db

I am looking for an artifact repository (Maven) for eXist, so that I can make queries against an eXist database.
I found http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/exist/exist and http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/exist/exist-xmldb but they do not work.
The only working artifacts I found are:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.exist-db</groupId>
      <artifactId>existdb-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <repository>
          <id>exist</id>
          <url>https://raw.github.com/eXist-db/mvn-repo/master/</url>
    </repository>
```

on this page https://github.com/eXist-db/mvn-repo but it does not seem so official and is already one year old.

Is there a better repository for eXist artifacts?

(I do not want to manually include packages because it is worse than using old links)

Comment: Actually the latest commit to that repository was June 11th 2014 - so they are definitely not a year old already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the current official place for eXist artifacts. At present eXist is not built using Maven, in the future we plan to use Maven (or similar) and create a more rigorous set of artifacts.